# os.path.isfile() doesn't work. Why?

Tags: python, listdir

I'm trying to do this:

```
import os
[x for x in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(x)]
[x for x in os.listdir('dirname') if os.path.isfile(x)]
[x for x in os.listdir(os.path.abspath('dirname')) if os.path.isfile(os.path.abspath(x))]
```

The first line works:

```
[x for x in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(x)]
```

But the next two:

```
[x for x in os.listdir('dirname') if os.path.isfile(x)]
```

and

```
[x for x in os.listdir(os.path.abspath('dirname')) if os.path.isfile(os.path.abspath(x))]
```

just output `[]`

Why?

Comment: because there is no `dirname` folder?

Comment: @njzk2 `dirname` just an example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you need to join the `dirname` with `x` , `os.listdir()` just lists the contents directly, the contents do not have full path.

Example -

```
[x for x in os.listdir('dirname') if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('dirname',x))]
```

When the full path is not given, `os.path.isfile()` searches in the current directory, hence when you give `'.'` to `os.listdir()` you get a correct list back.

---

Example -

Lets say some folder  - `/a/b/c` - has files - `x` and `y` in it.

when you do - `os.listdir('/a/b/c')` , the list returned looks like -

```
['x','y']
```

Even if you give absolute path inside `os.listdir()` , the files returned in the list would have relative path to the dir. You would manually need to join dir and `x` to get the correct results.

---

In your third example, it does not work because `os.path.abspath()` also works with current directory, so if you do something like -

```
os.path.abspath('somefile')
```

The result produced would be - `/path/to/current/directory/somefile` - it does not validate if that is a real file/dir or not.

It is clearly stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) (Emphasis mine) -

> **os.path.abspath(path)**
>
> Return a normalized absolutized version of the pathname path. On most platforms, **this is equivalent to calling the function normpath() as follows: `normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path))`.**

where `os.getcwd()` returns the path to current working directory.

Comment: Updated the answer with an example, `os.path.abspath(x)` also works with current directory not with `dirname` .

Comment: Thanks! I really understand now.

Answer (score 2):

`isfile()` is looking in the current directory.  Unless you include the directory name with the file name it has no idea where to find your files.