# If statement causes things to fail

Tags: python, if-statement

I need to read data from a set of files in a folder. Certain fields are updated using the filename as a reference. This will be appended to a larger dataframe to export to an excel.

When I run this code without the "if" it gives the expected result. It only throws an error on encountering a folder. So I introduced the if to check if its a file. Now it throws no error but also give no output.

```
import pandas as pnd
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
MyPath= "H:\Folder\Trial"
for CurrentFile in listdir(MyPath):
    if os.path.isfile(CurrentFile):
        .....Read some data.
```

I need to read data from the files in this folder. But right not it does nothing

Comment: Have you tried to [debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: what is the expected output...I feel like there is more going on inside the if statement

Comment: `os.path.isfile` expects an absolute path as parameter but `listdir` returns relative paths. Thus, `isfile` will always returns false. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157127/os-path-isfile-doesnt-work-why)

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé you've got the right idea but your terminology is wrong or misleading.  `os.path.isfile` expects absolute paths or paths relevant to the CWD `os.getcwd()`.  `listdir` returns *file names* including no other path information.

Comment: Thanks, @Gilles-Phillippe Paille for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks, @Philip Couling

Comment: I am trying to collect data from multiple excel files with similar tables. Also, I am adding a few conditional fields to this data. Further, I will be using the combined data for some basic statistical analysis

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Thanks for the suggestion. the link you shared is very useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get full path of file and then use `isfile` function, see below lines:
Also use r before mypath string which will use it as raw string or double \ instead of single \.

```
MyPath= r"H:\Folder\Trial"
for CurrentFile in listdir(MyPath):
    filepath = os.path.join(MyPath, CurrentFile)
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
```

Comment: Thanks, @Amit Nanaware, this worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @maheshgokhale welcome.. Please accept my answer :)